The formulas describing the relationship between the stereographic projection view of Möbius transformations and the injective biholomorphic map view
I want a better idea of the relationship between the stereographic projection interpretation of Möbius transformations and the injective biholomorphic map interpretation of Möbius transformations.
What I've worked out is the following:
Let $f:\mathbb{C}P^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^1$
Under the stereographic projection interpretation, we have
$$f(x+iy)=\frac{\left(\frac{x\cos\left(u\right)-y\sin\left(u\right)}{2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\right)\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\cos\left(v\right)+\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}-1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\sin\left(v\right)\right)\left(h+2\right)}{1+\frac{2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\sin\left(v\right)-\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}-1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\cos\left(v\right)}+i\frac{\left(\frac{x\sin\left(u\right)+y\cos\left(u\right)}{2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\right)\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\cos\left(v\right)+\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}-1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\sin\left(v\right)\right)\left(h+2\right)}{1+\frac{2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\sin\left(v\right)-\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}-1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\cos\left(v\right)}$$
where $u$ is the amount of rotation of the (unit) sphere about the $z$-axis, $v$ is the amount added to the polar angle $\phi$ (or, if you're a physicist, the polar angle $\theta$), and $h$ is the amount by which the unit sphere's $z$ component increases, which is a uniform increase by a real constant $h$ everywhere on the manifold
Since $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, it is complex differentiable.
Under the injective biholomorphic map interpretation, we have
$$f(x+iy)=\frac{a(x+iy)+b}{c(x+iy)+d}=\frac{\left(ax+b\right)\left(cx+d\right)+acy^{2}+i\left(ad-bc\right)y}{\left(cx+d\right)^{2}+c^{2}y^{2}}$$
where $ad-bc \neq 0$
I realize that if we pick one of $a,b,c$ or $d$ to be nonzero, then we can divide the numerator and denominator by that choice and we end up making it very obvious that there are three degrees of freedom. Since at least one of these 4 constants being nonzero is necessary (albeit insufficient) for $ad-bc \neq 0$, that means any Möbius transformation truly only has three degrees of freedom and there is always a very trivial division by a constant which makes obvious that there are three degrees of freedom.
The fact that there are three degrees of freedom makes sense given that in the stereographic projection model we have three degrees of freedom as well: rotation about the $z$-axis, increase (negative quantity if the angle is decreased) of the polar angle (referred to as inversion in this Geogebra simulation), and, finally, the amount by which the unit sphere's $z$ component increases (referred to as dilatation in this Geogebra simulation).
Given my definitions for these quantities, is it the case that $$\frac{\left(\frac{x\cos\left(u\right)-y\sin\left(u\right)}{2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\right)\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\cos\left(v\right)+\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}-1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\sin\left(v\right)\right)\left(h+2\right)}{1+\frac{2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\sin\left(v\right)-\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}-1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\cos\left(v\right)}+i\frac{\left(\frac{x\sin\left(u\right)+y\cos\left(u\right)}{2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\right)\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\cos\left(v\right)+\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}-1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\sin\left(v\right)\right)\left(h+2\right)}{1+\frac{2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\sin\left(v\right)-\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}-1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\cos\left(v\right)}=\frac{\left(ax+b\right)\left(cx+d\right)+acy^{2}+i\left(ad-bc\right)y}{\left(cx+d\right)^{2}+c^{2}y^{2}}$$
Have I made any calculation mistakes?
If not, is there a simpler way to express the constants $a,b,c,d$ (up to division by a constant) in terms of $u,v$ and $h$?
